# Plotting GLM models in ggplot2 r

Tags: r, ggplot2

Apologies for the obvious question but just incase there is a simple answer! Here is an example of what my data looks like:

```
DATA <- data.frame(
TotalAbund = sample(1:10),
TotalHab = sample(0:1),
TotalInv = sample(c("yes", "no"), 20, replace = TRUE)
)
DATA$TotalHab<-as.factor(DATA$TotalHab)
DATA
```

I've made the following plot:

```
p <- ggplot(DATA, aes(x=factor(TotalInv), y=TotalAbund,colour=TotalHab))
p + geom_boxplot() + geom_jitter()
```

I've created a model as follows:

```
MOD.1<-glm(TotalAbund~TotalInv+TotalHab, data=DATA)
```

However, I want to present fitted values from glm model rather than raw data. I know I can simply do it in visreg with:

```
visreg(MOD.1)
```

Is there a way to do this with ggplot too? Thanks

Comment: `ggplot2` works with data.frame's, not `glm` objects. So, no, you can't directly replicate a plot that takes as an input a `glm` object. But you can easily do whatever it is you wish in ggplot with some simple data manipulation.

Comment: Of note, please provide the desired output

Comment: Hi Alex, I've added a minimal data set above. First time I've tried to do that, so hope it works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

Create a "prediction frame" containing the relevant values for which you want to predict (if you had a continuous predictor, it would probably make more sense to include evenly spaced values, e.g. `seq(min(cont_pred),max(cont_pred),length=51)`)

```
pframe <- with(DATA,
       expand.grid(TotalInv=unique(TotalInv),
                   TotalHab=unique(TotalHab)))
```

Use the `predict` method to fill in the predicted values:

```
pframe$TotalAbund <- predict(MOD.1,newdata=pframe)
```

Add a layer to the graph.  The only annoying part is using `position_dodge` with a manually tweaked width to match the widths of the bars ... (I'm assuming here that you've saved your existing plot as `gg1` ...)

```
gg1 + geom_point(data=pframe,size=8,shape=16,alpha=0.7,
              position=position_dodge(width=0.75))
```

Comment: Great, that seems to have worked. I am using a log-linear model, is it possible to transform the y-axis to show exponentiated values? And how do I include 95% confidence intervals on the points? Sorry, for all the questions. I'm just unfamiliar with this way of plotting so finding it confusing. Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: you should probably ask another question, linking to this one ... some hints (if you want to figure it out yourself); see `scale_y_log10()` for one way to do y-axis scaling; for CIs, try `?predict.lm` and look for the "interval" argument  ...